# jQuery Tools Tabs: how to disable a tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using [jquery Tools tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/) and would like to disable a particular tab (e.g. current tab), sometime after it has been initialized, e.g. on button click.

This is the code that I have now, which does work, but I'm wondering whether there are better solutions.

Imagine I have a "disable" button that runs this:

```js
//disable all tabs except for current tab
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", function(ev,index){
    if (index != this.getIndex()){
        return false;
    }
})
```

and then an "enable tabs" button that does this:

```js
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div") //enables all tabs (by not disabling any)
```

The problem is, if I'm not mistaken, that I'm reinitializing the tabs each time, instead of modifying an the original existing instance. Is there a better solution?

Comment: not sure if you'd be interested in a different plugin, but [jqueryui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-disable) has this functionality out of the box.

Comment: @David thanks for the suggestion +1. I'll leave this question as a reference for anyone who might be interested in a jQuery Tools solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery TOOLS [Tabs Wizard Demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/wizard.html) you can alter the *onBeforeClick* event and return *false* on the tab you want to disable.

Here's a shortened copy of the code from tabs wizard documentation

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", function(event, index) {
    /* now we are inside the onBeforeClick event */
    if (index == 1 OR index == MYDISABLEDTAB)  {
        // when false is returned, tab cannot be activated
        return false;
    }

    // everything ok
});
```